# How to use date range picker along with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using date range picker javascript library To select range of date from user

```
                  $('#date_range').daterangepicker({
                    arrows:true,
                    dateFormat: 'd-M-yy',
                    rangeSplitter: 'to',
                    datepickerOptions: {
                         changeMonth: true,
                         changeYear: true,
                         minDate: new Date("01/01/2011") //Account created date
                    },
                    closeOnSelect: true,
                    onChange: function(){
                                    //ajax call goes here

                                    }
                  });
```

In my ajax call i am updating the screen with date range. but this on change function runs two times and ajax returns old date value. If need to use ajax functionality with on change function of date range picker.

If any one find solution for using onchange function at once with correct from and to date, intimate me please. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [documentation](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/) you find

> **onChange:** function, callback that
>   executes whenever the date input
>   changes (can happen twice on range
>   selections).

I have setup a little demo http://jsfiddle.net/ByzYX/16/

So onChange seems to be the wrong callback for your solution. I am not really sure what you want to update on screen and why you do ajax requests but you could try a if condition to execute you ajax call only once.

So `onOpen` set a flag to `true` and after performing ajax call set it to `false`. In `onChange` check this flag.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
$('#date_range').daterangepicker({
    "startDate": "01/01/2016",
    "endDate": "07/27/2016"
    }, function(start, end, label) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"/your_url",
            method: "GET", // or POST
            dataType: "json",
            data: {from: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), to: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')},
            success:function(result) {
                console.log("sent back -> do whatever you want now");
            }
        });
    });
```

This function works like `$("#date_range").change(function(){});`, but it has some parameters too.

You might want to change the date string to a valid date where you receive it, in case you want to do some filtering.

I found about this function on http://www.daterangepicker.com/, look there for more examples! :)