# Jquery datepicker range issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am new to jquery, and i am trying to solve a datepicker issue.

Basically, what i want is to display my items from xml file, by choosing a from and to date.

My ajax call looks like this

```
        function getSelectedItems(){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'myUrl',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'xml',
                async: false,
                success: parseXml
            });
        }
```

And the parseXML looks like this

```
function parseXml(xml)
        {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function()
            {
                $(".my-calendar").append($(this).find('title').text() + "<br />");
                $(".my-calendar").append($(this).find('pubDate').text() + "<br />");
            });
        }


$(document).ready( function() {


            $('#date_start').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

            $('#date_end').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

            });


            $('.btn-search').click(function (event) {

            });
        });
    });
```

Anyone, who can help my figuring this out?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information. Are you trying to select a date range from the date picker, which then those dates are posted in a payload/url request via ajax to your server, and returns xml records that have been filtered by the date range, and then display those records?

Comment: @Woodrow, Yes i want to select, lets say a date from 11-05-2017 to 30-05-2017, and it should show me all the items between those dates.

Comment: Okay, take a look at this post, it seems to answer what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995464/how-use-ajax-post-when-datepicker-change-date, and check out the linked JSFiddle from the post: http://jsfiddle.net/ner53k8k/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How use ajax post when datepicker change date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995464/how-use-ajax-post-when-datepicker-change-date)

Comment: @Woodrow, OP has a date range. Suggested duplicate thread is for a single date picker. May not be what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are working with date range, I would recommend using [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples) instead.

```
$('#date_range').daterangepicker({
    "startDate": "01/01/2017",
    "endDate": "02/01/2017"
}, function(start, end, label) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "myUrl",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'xml',
        data: {
            from: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            to: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        },
        success: parseXml
    });
});
```

Above code inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38615044/2777988